# How do Mogwai or Gremlins Drink?

Tags: gremlins

When a [Mogwai or a Gremlin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gremlins) is exposed to water, it multiplies.

But how then do they drink?

Comment: Couldn't they drink something that isn't water?

Comment: They take in fluids through their food (fruits, vegetables)?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The only time we see Mogwai reproduce from water is when it contacts their skin. There is no indication that drinking water (or taking it internally) results in spontaneous reproduction. It is also possible that only certain parts of the Mogwai are affected by water (such as the main torso). The general rule to never get them wet would then likely come from the difficulty in only getting the safe part of them wet.

Because most all foods contain some trace amount of water, it is unlikely the carbon based lifeform would survive without it.

Comment: There's actually several real-world species that live in arid environments and never drink water as such; they get all their hydration from their food. Domestic cats, for instance, have trouble feeling thirsty because their ancestors were adapted like that (though these days they do need to drink some water, particularly if you feed them dry food).

Comment: Just to point out, but in the movie they specifically say, "Don't give it water to drink."

Answer (score 57):

They drink on the back, directly from the tap :

[image: GREMLINS, 1984, drinking from the tap]

Comment: Wait a minute, _that's_ no water!

Answer (score 7):

In the [Gremlin film official novelisation](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/716175.Gremlins), it's revealed that the Mogwai don't drink. Ever.

It's reasonable to assume that this is because of the severe risk of spawning and because mogwai are able to ingest all the fluids that they need from their food...

> The kid looked at Rand pointedly. “I’m serious, mister.” he said.
>   “Sure,” Rand replied. **“It’s just that animals need water to drink, right?**”
>   **“This one doesn’t.”**
>   “You sure?”

Later in the same film we see Gremlins drinking alcoholic beverages so it's clear that they can imbide fluids (orally) without budding.

Comment: Mightn't that be a case of unreliable narrator, though?

Comment: @GhotiandChips - Well, in the book he has it for several days before his "accident". He's evidently had sufficient time to learn about its eating patterns.

Comment: Humans can last 3 to 5 days without water, and camels six to seven months, */edit/* who knows how long Mogwais (who are aliens) can last? I don't think Pete does!

Comment: From the wiki *"The mogwai were created to be able to **survive** in almost every environment and also to reproduce very easily"*, which might imply they're durable in their thirst! Though it may also mean they don't need water at all, supporting your answer.

Comment: @Ghotiandchips - The wiki is fan-written. Without a reference, it's basically worthless.

Comment: I always wondered, if you can't feed them after midnight; what time the next day can you feed them?

Comment: @sueelleker - It's not made clear. Nor is it clear which midnight (it's always midnight *somewhere*. And what about planets with solar periods greater/less than 24 hours.